# What precisely is "implicit differentiation" and what results does it use?

Tags: calculus

Introductory calculus teaches something called "implicit differentiation".

What precisely is this?

Must it always involve the Implicit Function Theorem?

For example, when we use "implicit differentiation" to find the gradient of the curve $x^2+y^2=1$ at $(0,1)$, must we use the Implicit Function Theorem? Or can we use only simpler results?

(Also, what about the Chain Rule? Must it always be used when we do "implicit differentiation"?)

Comment: I think of it like this: suppose $y$ is a function which satisfies $x^2 + y(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x$, $-1 < x < 1$. Taking the derivative of both sides of this equation reveals that $2x + 2 y(x) y’(x) = 0$. We can then solve for $y’(x)$.

Comment: Excellent video on the [intuition of implicit differentiation by 3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb40J4N1fa4). Might be worth checking out

Comment: Say $xy=17$. By implicit differentiation, $x(dy/dx)+y=0$, so $dy/dx=-y/x$. No Chain Rule.